# Embedd ICC profile in PDF

Tags: linux, pdf

I am generating a PDF where all the graphics are drawn in \DeviceRGB in the sRGB color space. I would like to convert the PDF into a different Color Profile using an ICC profile and embed the ICC profile, but I can't find a good tool to do this.

I have tried ImageMagick, but that rasterizes the PDF which is undesirable, and I have tried using ghostscript, but while that converts the colors, it doesn't embed the ICC profile.

Is there any tool available for linux that does what I want?